# How to prevent someone clone PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, protection, firmware, security

ACT 1

Okay I know there is code protection system on PIC. But it is preventing someone read the code, not copy. It looks still easy to clone and run on another circuit. Can you suggest another methods for providing security?  Like how can I insert an encrypt/decrypt system or serial number system to my project?

ACT 2

How about we will think about all MCU's even microprocessors... Is program security reliable on other systems? Or can we encrypt our memory somehow?

Comment: How can you copy the code if you can't read it? Methods of providing security depend on the threat model you have in mind.

Comment: Can't read a meaningful code but just .hex file and it is just enough to clone. Or it is just what I understood from my researches.

Comment: HEX file *is* the most meaningful code you can get from any PIC with or without protection. There is no C source codes stored in the MCUs.

Comment: Which IC?  If you can extract the hex file you can reverse engineer it to get useable assembly code.  Some ICs do have read protection.  You never get access to the original source code as it is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this with a PIC, from what I've read there are also labs in china that can defeat code protections on a PIC. Even microchip admits this:

> Very often the intellectual property (IP) of an embedded product lives
>   within the code of the microcontroller. In today's market place, it
>   only takes a few weeks to extract that code despite the usage of
>   traditional "code protect" features. At a moderate expense, many third
>   party options are widely available on the internet who are capable to
>   obtain HEX files from the microcontroller. This type of conterfeit
>   puts in danger companies IP and could consequently lead to significant
>   revenue loss or open various backdoors to malicious firmware.

Source: https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/security-ics/cryptoauthentication/counterfeit-protection/secure-boot

But they do have the [ATECC608A](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATECC608A) to secure boot a PIC and even obfuscate I2C communications to prevent copying.

Comment: That looks effective. I'll make some research about it. It will be awesome if you have some source.

Comment: Some source? like source code? Links? what?

Comment: like links, I don't know much about co-processors, cryptography on MCU's... Any 101 documents will work. And if you don't mind, can you take a look ACT 2 part of my question?

Answer (score 2):

Code protection will prevent *easy* copying of the code since it disables the normal ability to read the code out of the flash though the programming pins.

Keep in mind that it is almost impossible to thwart a dedicated attacker with access to advanced tools on almost any platform. Here is one example hack that uses UV light to clear the protection fuse  on PIC...

https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=40

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any microcontroller code protection scheme can be broken, and perhaps surprisingly easily and inexpensively. That's simply a fact, and it doesn't apply specifically to any family of processor. If you have a successful (financially) product that reaches a wide market and is visible, most likely someone WILL try to copy it, either by reverse engineering or cracking your code.

An effective method of protection that works in some circumstances is to put vital portions of functionality or data in the cloud and require access to the internet for full functionality. Sometimes enough features can be implemented that that provides significant benefits for the user.

I don't have a warm feeling about the real application of some of these schemes as they tend to cause inconvenience or worse for legitimate users and seem to me to be particularly associated with buggy products. But that's opinion based.

An alternate method of protection uses legal technology- by embedding an "Easter Egg" you can detect the illegitimate direct copy of firmware and take action to at least keep infringing products out of your main markets.